# I Want List Of Employees, If Emp Are Having Commission I Want To Get Comm(numbers) If Emp is Not Having A Comm Then Sorry

Tags: sql, oracle

*Using Decode..

```
SELECT ENAME, SAL, 
DECODE
(
COMM,
COMM >=0, (SELECT COMM FROM EMP WHERE COMM>=0),--I KNOW THIS IS  A MISTAKE 
'NO COMM'
) COMMISSION
FROM EMP
ORDER BY COMISSION
```

- Can we write Arithmetic operations in `DECODE`

THIS IS THE ERROR I GOT

```
COMM >=0, (SELECT COMM FROM EMP WHERE COMM>=0),
     *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Indoors voice, please! No need to SHOUT WHILE WRITING YOUR POST.

Comment: Accidental use of the capslock key was sometimes excusable 20 years ago. Not anymore.

Comment: Thanks for enlighnemt ... I wrote that because to be clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this..

```
 SELECT ENAME, SAL, 
    (Case when COMMISSION>0 then Cast(COMMISSION as Varchar2(20)) Else 'Sorry' End) as  Comments
    FROM EMP
    ORDER BY COMISSION
```

Comment: @AMITHSINGH THANKS AMITH ... IT WAS USEFUL BUT i WANT COMM FIGURES (REAL) IN THE PLACE OF 'COMM'

Comment: @TEMPLATE i edited my answer try now

Comment: getting this error bro `ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis`

Comment: can you put your update query

Comment: @TEMPLATE  i think it is because we gives alias as decode chage it to decodes or any thoer name...deocde is internaldunxdtion so can not use as alias

Comment: bro can you elaborate it ...upto now I know that `Decode` is sql use of `if-then-else` statement

Comment: is it work or not...what to elaborate...its simplae case statement

Comment: you can search on google is also use for if and else

Comment: ok Thanks you @Amith ... no bro it is not working

Comment: try now i edited my answer

Comment: no bro... [sql fiddel](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/!) try here to execute the statment

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f12e/2 its worknig bro see here

Comment: yeah bro it is! There is just a variable rename.. and I replaced it.. it is working fine thank you ... but how can I do it with DECODE ?

Comment: i know sql server friend...not oracle..case can b used in any rdms so i answered it....dont forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using DECODE, but the CASE example by **AmitSingh** is cleaner

```
SELECT ename,
       sal,
       DECODE(SIGN(comm), 1, TO_CHAR(comm), 'No Comm') commission
  FROM emp
```

The SIGN function will return a -1 if comm is < 0, 0 if comm is 0 and 1 if comm > 0, so if SIGN(comm) returns 1, then it means comm is greater than 0.  Otherwise there is no commission.